# An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration while using Autofac

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection, interface, autofac

This is the way we register the classes using `Autofac`

```
builder.Register(c => new FileLogger(ILogger)).As<ILogger>().SingleInstance();

var sizeinkb= Convert.ToInt32(configuration.GetValue<string>("Settings:SizeInKb"));

builder.RegisterType<Broker>().As<IBroker>().WithParameter("size", sizeinkb).SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<MainClass>().As<IMainClass>().SingleInstance();

var container = builder.Build();
ContainerFactory.SetContainer(container);
```

Here is our class

```
public class MainClass:IMainClass
{
    public MainClass(IBroker broker,ILogger logger)
    {
        _broker = broker,
        _logger = logger
    }
}
```

Here is the broker class

```
public class Broker:IBroker 
{
     public Broker(ILogger logger,
             int size)
     {

     }
}
```

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = MainClass (ReflectionActivator), Services = [MyProject.IMainClass], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MyProject.MainClass' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'MyProject.IBroker  broker' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MyProject.IBroker, MyProject.ILogger)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach where the dependencies can be resolved during the lambda setup

```
//...removed for brevity

var sizeinkb = Convert.ToInt32(configuration.GetValue<string>("Settings:SizeInKb"));
builder.Register(c => new Broker(c.Resolve<ILogger>(), sizeinkb))
    .As<IBroker>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<MainClass>().As<IMainClass>().SingleInstance();

var container = builder.Build();
ContainerFactory.SetContainer(container);
```